# Python selecting files by last letter and extension

Tags: python

I have two files in a folder: `with name_E.mat` and `name_N.mat`. How can I select them by the last letter+extension?
The following code is what I tried:

```
filedir = r'C:\Users\320037415\Documents\Depth\Proefpersonen\Sub70'
enterprise = glob.glob(filedir + "/_E.mat")
neolead = glob.glob(filedir + "/_N.mat")
filelist = neolead + enterprise
```

Comment: What exactly does "How can I select them by the last letter+extension?" mean? You want to filter the list?

Comment: I'm not sure what all these glob-thingamajingies are, but you can do something like [filename for filename in directory if filename[-6:] == '_E.mat'][0]

Comment: I want to have 1 filelist but divided by 2 groups. One group ending with _E and one group with _N.

Comment: Like, `e_list = [item for item in filelist if item.split('.')[0].endswith('E')]`?

Comment: Well, the directory names suggest that they are separated already, so why not `filelist = [neolead, enterprise]` to give a nested list?

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` as a wildcard for file names:

```
enterprise = glob.glob(filedir + "/*_E.mat")
neolead = glob.glob(filedir + "/*_N.mat")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `os` module.

**Demo:**

```
import os

filedir = r'C:\Users\320037415\Documents\Depth\Proefpersonen\Sub70'
filelist = [file for file in os.listdir(filedir) if file.endswith(("_E.mat", "_N.mat")) ]
```